# Gradle bundling

Tags: java, gradle, deployment, jar, gradle-plugin

I have a gradle + spring project

The project structure follows the recommended structure

```
src/main
   /resources
test/main
    /resources
```

On issuing ./gradlew build, its creating a fat jar.

1. How to create a separate jar for only dependencies via gradle and the one for the actual source code in src/main
2. How to exclude properties/yml file from src/main/resources so that its outside the jar and doesnt need recompilation/repackaging in case of any changes to the properties

Please let me know if any more information is required

Comment: _pushing the dependencies onto the server_ A server? What server?

Comment: Currently we have not setup up a build server etc. We are building locally and uploading the jars to the server where it runs